# Getting a 'segmentation fault' error when trying to use strcat to concatenate a char and a string

Tags: c

I keep getting this error `segmentation fault` when I am trying to access a character in a string and add that onto another string. The code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
// function to find the initials of a name
void findInitials(char* name)
{
    char* initials = "";
    bool initialCreated = false;
    int n = 0;

    while(name[n] != '\0')
    {
        if(name[n] != ' ')
        {
            if(initialCreated == false)
            {
                //this is where I am facing the issue
                strcat(initials, &name[n]);
                printf("INITIAL: %c\n", name[n]);
                initialCreated = true;
            }

            if(name[n+1] == ' ')
            {
                initialCreated = false;
                n++;
            }
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `string` supposed to be? It's not a standard type in C

Comment: This looks more like a terrible C++ than C.

Comment: oops, I should probably fix that

Comment: Rule of a thumb, writing strings into not allocated memory is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`char* initials = "";` is not `char initials[SOME_SIZE] = {0};` You are not allocating any memory, you just take a pointer and start writing some characters to memory, which is not supposed to be written to. In general segmentation fault tells you that you're modifing a piece of memory that you're not allowed to. That's what happens in your case.